# Отправка файла через form методом action="file/upload.php"

Tags: action, html, php, form

Здравсвуйте. Есть форма:

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

В ней атрибут action="upload.php". Но если изменить его `action="file/upload.php"`, то ничего не работает. Фаил `upload.php`, конечно, перенес в папку "file", но эффекта нет. Поясните, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно пишут:

```
action="/file/upload.php"
```

Либо полный путь. Уточните вопрос, если я вас не так понял.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо написать:

```
/file/upload.php
```

Comment: все равно не работает